# How to create a war file of Spring MVC Project and deploy it in JBOSS 5?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, deployment, jboss5.x

How to create a war file of Spring MVC Project anddeploy it in JBOSS 5?

Comment: Create a WAR file: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html.  JBOSS deploy: http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/userguide/1.0/en-US/html/deployment.html

Comment: Which IDE you are using?